# ubuntu 16.04 AMD HD 6000 serise graphics driver

Tags: 16.04, radeon

want to know that when the graphics driver for amd radeon HD 6000 will release ??

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu includes an open-source driver which is enabled by default. It provides baseline functionality, which is usually enough for the average user.

Up until 16.04, AMD provided a proprietary driver ([fglrx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Radeon_Software_Crimson#Linux)) that provided a few extra features (including better performance) for newer cards. However, with the release of 16.04, fglrx is no longer supported and will not work with the X display stack.

AMD is focusing their efforts on a new driver, amdgpu that will serve as a replacement for the fglrx driver. However, it is only available for 14.04 at the moment. AMD has announced plans to provide a driver compatible with kernel 4.4 (used by 16.04) later this year.

Unfortunately this means that if you want a feature not provided by the open-source driver, for now you will need to:

- downgrade to 15.10 or 14.04
- wait for the newer driver